# Making angular2-cookie secure and encrypted

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, encryption, cryptography

I'm currently using [Angular2-Cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie) which helped me set up and use cookies throughout my application. It's working really well so far but I'd like to make sure the data inside my cookie is safe for the most part. I have set up the secure flag to true and that only prevents it to being sent through an unsecure connection (so only available via https!) which is good but once it's sent through https, I can see the information in plaintext. So I'd also like to encrypt the cookie or set the cookie httponly.

Since I'm not a security expert, I was wondering, what's the best approach to proceed? What can I do on my end to make sure the data is secure inside the cookie? Encryption, sure.... which one? HttpOnly... okay, how do I set it up for this cookie? What else?

Currently, e.g. I'm putting an email address inside my cookie like below:

```
this.cookieService.put("emailAddress",model.email, options);
```

where options are where I set the `secure : true` flag.

Comment: HttpOnly only suggests to the browser to disallow JavaScript running on the page from accessing the cookie value. It's still stored in the browser, available to the end-user, and not encrypted.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert too, but in my opinion the best way is serialize all the cookie on a json and encrypt. This way you can send sensitive data to server encrypted.